# Is there a way to know if a function is run from test cmd in RUST?

Tags: rust

Hello my RUST project is mainly based on filesystem.
All the files will be saved in the folder returned by the function `get_home_dir()`

```
pub fn get_home_dir() -> PathBuf {
    let mut path = match home::home_dir() {
        Some(path) => path,
        None => PathBuf::new(),
    };
    path.push(Path::new("my_dir"));

    DirBuilder::new()
        .recursive(true)
        .create(path.clone())
        .unwrap();

    path
}
```

I have conflicts when I want to run tests.
So I want `get_home_dir()` to return:

- `/currentuser/my_dir_test` -> on `cargo test`
- `/currentuser/my_dir` -> on `cargo run`

Is there a way to set a variable value based on the environment? like env = "test" | "run"

I come from JS world. With JEST I would be able to do something like

`const dirname = PROCESS.env.NODE_ENV === "test" ? "my_dir_test" : "my_dir"`

Is there a rust alternative to do this?

Comment: You can use `cfg!(test)` to decide, but IIRC it will only be set on unit tests and I think also doctests but not integration tests. Maybe I'm wrong though.

Comment: If you want to capture integration tests too, consider testing for an [enviroment variable set by Cargo](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/environment-variables.html#environment-variables-cargo-sets-for-crates) instead.